# problem with making Web Request in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, rest, webrequest

I am making restful requests in my silverlight app, I want to get information that might be pushed to the page so i continously make the request to get the updated data, doing something like

```
.... 
Uri url = new Uri(theUrl);WebClient wc = new WebClient();  
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += RetreiveUserMessagesResponse;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

My problem is, for some reason, once i make the request (and it returns some data) subsequent requests keep returning the same data and does not change! (almost like it cached the request and its saying, i did this already let me just return what i got before), when i copy the URL and put it in my browser I get the expected behavior, why is this happening when i am making the requests through the Silverlight app? 
Thanks for your help
Daniel

Comment: What kind of URL is it? Where is it hosted? I'm not able to duplicate this issue using an ASPX page that outputs the time onto the page and running on the visual studio dev web server.

Comment: Its hosted on  a remote s erver, its just a url that looks like http://ipaddress:port/Service1.svc/MethodsName?arg1=1&arg2=2 etc

Comment: The web client should get the new data unless there is some kind of caching being done on the server. If you post the actual url we could try testing it to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue.

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/14453/70533.aspx

What it recommends for a work around is putting some random, unused parameter at the end of the URI to ensure a unique URI on each request.